# Matching the same string in multiple ways with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('^(.+)\'s (.+)$',re.I)

string = "bill's uncle's pony"

matchObjects = pattern.finditer(string)

for i in matchObjects:
    if i:
        print i.group(1)
        print i.group(2)
```

This produces the output:

```
bill's uncle
pony
```

When I hoped it would produce the output

```
bill's uncle
pony
bill
uncle's pony
```

That is, I want all the ways in which the string matches. This code only gives me one of them. Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: The `+` qualifier is **greedy**, meaning it takes as much text as possible. That's why you got `bill's uncle` instead of `bill`. You'll have to experiment with non-greedy qualifiers to get what you want, but note that those will be *different* regular expressions. You can't have just one RE for multiple match possibilities.

Comment: This link may or may not help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667528/regular-expression-listing-all-possibilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "That is, I want all the ways in which the string matches. This code only gives me one of them."

That's not true. It gives you the *only* way in which your regex matches your input. That's what the [greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10764399) `+` quantifier does: it skips over all possibilites *except the last*--as long as a match is still possible.

So you'll never get just `uncle's` with your current regex.

Perhaps you could do this twice, first with your current greedy regex

```
^(.+)\'s (.+)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ftB5hybgBC-SFRDW)

and then again with the [reluctant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10764399) version:

```
^(.+?)\'s (.+)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/yJCyRKOyPvsr8KUi)

Greedy matches `bill's uncle` and `pony`. Reluctant  matches `bill` and `uncle's pony`.

But the concept of "finding all matches" doesn't really make sense. A regular expression matches, or does not match, an input string in exactly one way.

(I'm surprised the debuggex images are exactly the same.)

---

Please consider bookmarking the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) for future reference.

Answer (score -1):

Previously suggested the DOTALL but that was no good. Try using the non-greedy modifier "?"

```
pattern = re.compile('^(.+?)\'s (.+?)$',re.I)
```

Still does not give exactley the desired output, but maybe it'll help put us on the right track.

output:

```
bill
uncle's pony
```