# Convert regular expressions to readable text

Tags: php, regex

Is there a way in PHP, that you can convert the following regular expression

```
3.[0123]
```

To

```
3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3
```

Thank you for looking in to this :)

EDIT:
Sorry i was unclear :/
I want to read out XML, and show that on a web-page, and i want to show that to users.
In that XML, there is a regular expression like this one:

**3.[0123]**

My question is: Can I convert a regular expression like the one above me, to a readeble text that the average user understands :)

So that the user sees this: **3.1, 3.2, 3.3, ...**

And not this: **3.[0123]** (this is an example, it can be every number).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What you have tired? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes, note `3.[0123]` says `3` any character then `0`, `1`, `2`, or `3`. I think you could do `(3\.0|3\.1|3\.2|3\.3)`.. is that more readable?

Comment: There sure is. `3.0|3.1|3.2|3.3`. A better question is; why are you looking to do this?

Comment: With [THIS](https://regex101.com/) you can work, test and play with your regex

Comment: No, the 3.[0123] is the data of the XML

Comment: I think @chris85 meant: Is it possible that there could be other regex like your one?

Comment: Okay, so what about using the `or`s as previously mentioned, is that easier to read? `(3\.0|3\.1|3\.2|3\.3)` You also could just not use a regex and check the literal value.

Comment: A.t.m. that is the only regex in the xml

Comment: This works :) (3\.0|3\.1|3\.2|3\.3), thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `or` to make the regex a bit more readable.

```
(3\.0|3\.1|3\.2|3\.3)
```

Also note the escaping of `.`. The `.` is a special character in regex and means "any character" your regex as is would have allowed more than just `3.0`, `3.1`, `3.2`, or `3.3`. You also should use anchors to ensure that is the only value in the string. So a final version (without delimiters):

```
^(3\.0|3\.1|3\.2|3\.3)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$start= "3.[0123]";
$value = explode("[", $start);
$sequences = str_split($value[1]);
array_pop($sequences);
foreach ($sequences as $sequence) {
    $array[] = $value[0].$sequence;
}
var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking to expand a regular expression into all possibilities, i.e. a list of all results that would satisfy it. The general case for this is a seriously complex problem, and would regularly result in an infinite number of possibilties (where `.+` is used, for example). See [Regular expression listing all possibilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667528/regular-expression-listing-all-possibilities) for a bit more discussion of that.

For a simple case though, where there is a single character class, it's easy enough to expand out the possibilities,

```
<?php
$base = '3.[0123]';

// Match a single character class, e.g. [0123] or [ABC]
$matches = [];
preg_match('/\[(\w+)\]/', $base, $matches);

list($expansion, $options) = $matches;

$possibilities = [];

// For each possible character in the class, replace the full original
// character class in the expression with that character
foreach (str_split($options) as $option)
{
    $possibilities[] = str_replace($expansion, $option, $base);
}

print_r($possibilities);
```

=

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3.0
    [1] => 3.1
    [2] => 3.2
    [3] => 3.3
)
```