# PCRE to find all possible matching values

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I am using PCRE in PHP and I need to find a way to generate say an array of all possible matching values. Any ideas?

For example if I had `R[2-9]{1}` I would want:

```
R2
R3
R4
R5
R6
R7
R8
R9
```

Comment: There's no easy way to do that.  Can you tell us more about why you're asking this question?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have a number of fields that use PCRE for validation already, a number of them are short enough that I want to be to present all the possible options in a <select> for the user. Figured I could reuse all the PCRE string I already wrote.

Comment: If they're as simple as the one you gave, it would be faster to write code that creates the menus on a case by case basis than something to parse each regex and create all of the available matches (which might be difficult for non-trivial regexes).

Comment: Although even a simple regexp (eg \d{1,9}) can give an enormous selection for your dropdowns... more than you'd want to create

Comment: Right but in the case of all of my regex expressions the total amount possible is always less than 50. Thus why I wanted to get this going. I searched considerably last night for a way to do this and came up short.

Comment: -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248519/how-can-i-expand-a-finite-pattern-into-all-its-possible-matches

Answer (score 1):

PCRE does not have the ability to generate sample strings based on a regular expression.  I do not know of a PHP library that does.  Libraries that can do this usually support only limited regex flavors and need artificial restrictions for regexes like `R[2-9]*` that can match an infinite number of strings.

If you only need to do this for very simple regexes like `R[2-9]` then it shouldn't be to hard to either:

- Parse the regex in your own code to generate the sample values, or to use another mechanism.
- Or to use your own mechanism to specify "R followed by a digit between 2 and 9" from which your code can then generate both the regex and the list of sample values.
- Or, if the regexes are hard-coded in your source code, just to type out the list of values by hand.