# Find all matching strings of a regular expression (without + and * operator)

Tags: regex

I want to enumerate all possible strings matched by a regular expression.
All the regular expressions I want to match against have no `*` or `+` only something like `x*{5}` which is equivalent to `x?x?x?x?x?`.

so given any regular expression like the one below:

```
[a-c]?cdr*{0,2}
```

i want all strings matching the expression. Thus the library or program shall output something like this:

```
cd, acd, bcd, ccd, cdr, acdr, bcdr, ccdr, cdrr, acdrr, bcdrr, ccdrr
```

I don't care about the language it is implemented in as long as it runs in linux.

refinement: if the regular expression is transformed into a deterministic finite automaton the automaton must be representable as a directed acyclic graph. that's why the possible output strings must be enumerable (not infinitely long strings).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word

Comment: @Mithun: The linked question is totally unrelated to this one?

Comment: This one is closer to what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248519/how-can-i-expand-a-finite-pattern-into-all-its-possible-matches

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Your "regex" consists of a max of 3 characters, unless I am mistaken, yet your results have more than three characters?

Comment: @FailedDev the *{2} operator means 0 or 2 repetitions of the last character.

Comment: @Alex Yes. And you have maybe a single a/b/c in the start therefore 3 right?

Comment: @FailedDev uhm what about the cd in the middle? it shall read a prefix: a,b or c followed by a cd followed by at most 2 occurrences of r. making `c cd rr` a 3 character pattern shall match?

Comment: @Alex OK now I get what you meant.. So [abc]?cdr{0,2} is what you need I assume.

Comment: @FailedDev (a|b|c)? and [abc]? should be equivalent. how does this help me enumerate ALL matching strings?

Comment: @NarendraYadala thank you for the link, I was hopeing for some library or implementation of this.

Comment: Your regex syntax is wrong, as @FailedDev points out. `x*{2}` doesn't mean 0 to 2 repetitions of `x` (at least not in any regex flavor I know); you want `x{0,2}`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Even I was getting an error in all languages and I was using RegexBuddy to test it. But POSIX BRE and GNU BRE does not give an error, but they do not work like OP says either. They match `{2}` literally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this Java library will help you with this http://code.google.com/p/xeger/ and since it is Java, it would also run on Linux.

Comment: Ah this looks very promising, I will accept as soon as I have tested whether it fulfils my requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a python solution for this problem: [https://github.com/asciimoo/exrex](https://github.com/asciimoo/exrex/)

it handles * and + operators as well